# Changing format of a clone date picker value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cloned input value from the jQuery date picker and I am trying to change the format in the cloned element only.

Shown Field :

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" class="datepicker-input--checkin datepicker"  
     value="1/1/2017" />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />

$(function() {
    var $button = $('.datepicker-input--checkin').clone();
    $('.package').html($button);
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    });
});
```

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/7/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the formatted date you can bind the  `changeDate` event on datepicker and can format the value in the binded method.

`$(".datepicker").datepicker().on('changeDate', dateChangeListener);`

`function dateChangeListener(event) {`

```
var formattedDate = event.format('dd.mm.yy');
$(".datepicker").val(formattedDate);
```

`}`

Comment: is it possible to change the format without touching the date picker but adding the code to only the clone function?